# cfheader cfcontent Mobile Browser download unsuccessful

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, coldfusion

I'm serving up a .ePub file for download without displaying the url to the client.  The code below works in any browser on a PC/Mac but will not work in mobile browsers, at least in Android which is what I have for testing currently.  I get a 'download unsuccessful' message every time.  Any ideas???

Code:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=#authStuff.lastname#-#theTitle#.ePub" /><cfcontent type="application/unknown" file="d:\home\sample.net\bookSource\#book.ePub#">
```

Answer (score 0):

all the examples I've seen and used ave a space between the attachment; and the filename, so  you could try:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#authStuff.lastname#-#theTitle#.ePub" />
```

Also, use FireBug or Fiddler to make sure the header is coming through unaltered. Do desktop browsers prompt you to save with the right filename?

EDIT: Just tried your code out on ios with a pdf and that happily consumed the pdf, so the space may be a red herring, however it makes me think it's probably worth trying out the code below to try to see if it's an ePub thing or a headers thing:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=something.pdf" />
<cfcontent type="application/unknown" file="#expandpath('something.pdf')#">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following two changes to your code:

1) Wrap the content-disposition filename in quotes (either using doubled up quotes to escape them, or **#Chr( 34 )#** so they're not confused with your value attribute quotes).

2) Use **application/octet-stream** as the content type (should really be application/epub+zip but Android doesn't seem to recognize it).

This seems to work on Android 2.3.5 at least.

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#Chr(34)##authStuff.lastname#-#theTitle#.ePub##Chr(34)#">
<cfcontent type="application/octet-stream" file="d:\home\sample.net\bookSource\#book.ePub#">
```

Comment: Strange. I was able to replicate the "download unsuccessful" error with your code but changing to this definitely fixed it for me on Android 2.3. Is it possible the old code is being cached? Have you tried a simple test where the filename and file path are hard coded values to rule out problems with your query values? eg. filename=#Chr(34)#test.epub#Chr(34)# and file="D:\temp\test.epub"

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it still won't download.  I've tested on Android 4.0.4 and on 2.3.  I don't believe that it is related to the file name, as this code works perfect on iOS, Windows, etc.  I wonder if there is another way to serve up the file without giving the direct path?....

Comment: If you're using Apache as your web server you could try X-SendFile: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2170-Streaming-Secure-Files-Efficiently-With-ColdFusion-And-MOD-XSendFile.htm, but I fear you'll still run into problems with the http content type, which for me was clearly the issue with the Android browser.