# Download Unsuccessful on Mobile Browser (Android) when using cfheader and cfcontent in Coldfusion

Tags: android, iis, mobile, coldfusion, httpresponse

When I run the code below from a desktop browser, there is no problem.

However, when I try it from either Android Chrome or the default Android browser, I always get a "Download Unsuccessful" message.

Code:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes">

<cfcontent type="text/calendar" reset="Yes">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='inline; filename="newAppointment.ics"'>

<cfoutput>BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Some organization//some application//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20120925T072912Z-140@http://localhost/www/
CREATED:20140925T072912Z
DTSTAMP:20140922T090500Z
DTSTART:20140922T090500Z
DTEND:20140922T100500Z
DESCRIPTION:Please attend this sample meeting
SUMMARY:Invitation to attend training
LOCATION:Earth
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:periklis@example.com
ORGANIZER;CN=periklis@example.com:mailto:periklis@example.com
LAST-MODIFIED:20140925T072912Z
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR</cfoutput>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="no">
```

I have tried using both "text/calendar" and "application/octet-stream" for the content type, and both "inline" and "attachment" for the content disposition.  I have also tried the filename with  and without quotes... all to no avail.

We are running Coldfusion 10 on an IIS server, and we added this configuration to the server so we can download an .ics file directly from the server now.  However, we want to generate a single use file dynamically and serve it to the user.

IIS server setting:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".ics" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ics" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Using Chrome's Remote Debugging, I can see this coming through as the Response header from the code above.  (Note:  I see a lot of people put cfheader first, then cfcontent... but if I follow that order, the content disposition is not passed along so I've been putting cfcontent first.)

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 21:31:31 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP='NOI DSP COR LAW NID CUR ADMa OUR DELa IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV STA'
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="newAppointment.ics"
Content-Type: text/calendar;charset=UTF-8
```

I've scoured the internet, and the closest thing I've found was another stackoverflow question with some suggestions but no accepted answer.  Also... being a new user, I can't comment on it to ask if an answer was found.

[cfheader cfcontent Mobile Browser download unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926792/cfheader-cfcontent-mobile-browser-download-unsuccessful)

I tried to give as many details that I can think of.  Let me know if more information would be helpful in solving the oddity.

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code works on CF9/IIS7 serving to Chrome on Adroid 4.2.2. Your response header suggests you're on IIS6. Don't have an answer, but my hunch would be that's where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this from "inline" to "attachment"

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='inline; filename="newAppointment.ics"'>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=""newAppointment.ics""">
```